# How can I use all import, modules.export, and export in the same ts file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a typescript file in which there are some functions for validating objects of different classes. So, **I have to** import those classes into the ts file. For instance,

```
import { UserDetail } from "../../entity/user/userDetail";
```

The following block of code depicts a function which is used for validating the objects of the mentioned class.

```
export function validateSignUpData(userDetail:UserDetail):Array<String>{

    let errorMessages = new Array<String>();
    /* Some Code */
```

As you can see the imported class has been used as the function's input type. Now the problem is that it seems we are not allowed to use both **import** and **module.exports** simultaneously! Therefore, I am not able to use **require** in order to get the mentioned function in the Node server file.

When I add the following block of code to my ts file, the following exception is thrown!

```
module.exports = validateSignUpData;
```

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '# object'

**Question**: How can I use all **import**, **modules.export**, and **export** in the same ts file?

I will be glad if someone can help me with the situation. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Of course you're able to import that function with require. Just do it like this:

```
const {validateSignUpData} = require('./my-module.js')
```

And pay attention to require the compiled javascript file, not the typescript file. They may be in different folders, depending on your build setup.

Comment: How can I fined these compiled, ultimate JS files and put their addresses into the require function?!

Comment: Read your `tsconfig.js`, there's an `outDir` key that points to the destination folder. If there is none, they probably can be found in the same folder as the typescript files. If there still aren't any, look into all your project folders except for `node_modules` (or run `tsc` to compile the scripts)